# Iterate array and print different string outputs

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to understand for loops and arrays a little better as a newbie. Can I print a string array using a for loop and get different outputs for each string on a new line, for example "string1 to uppercase", "string2 to lowercase" as I have demonstrated with the single println statements.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Examples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       String[] strings = new String[] {"LOWERCASE","uppercase","char at index","flow"};

         System.out.println(strings[0].toLowerCase()); //can i do this//
         System.out.println(strings[1].toUpperCase()); //with a       //
         System.out.println(strings[3].charAt(3));     //simple       //
         System.out.println(strings[0].length());      //for loop     //

         for (String name: strings){     

             System.out.println(name);
         }   
    }    
}
```

Use a for loop to get the same result as the single `println` statements.

Comment: What you have used is not a simple for loop, it is an enhanced one, a for-each loop...

Comment: You mean if you can do inside a for-loop what you did in each of the lines where you access the array positions directly?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a for loop ? What is your motive here ?

Comment: No motive, just trying to teach myself and was wondering if it is possible.

Comment: Yes @lealceldeiro, exactly as you have described was what I was asking. I have no practical reason for it however was asking out of my own curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

You can define different conditions for your different actions on a `String` and check them inside a simple for loop (that is one with a number getting incremented per step).
See this example which uses a modulo operation to distinguish between 4 different cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = new String[] {"LOWERCASE","uppercase","char at index","flow"};

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {     
        if (i % 3 == 3) {
            System.out.println(strings[i].toLowerCase());
        } else if (i % 3 == 2) {
            System.out.println(strings[i].toUpperCase());
        } else if (i % 3 == 1) {
            System.out.println(strings[i].charAt(3));
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(strings[i].length());
        }
    }
}
```

Run it and then find out what caused the output.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is extending your for-each loop to execute each string operation to each entry in the list like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Examples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] strings = new String[] {"LOWERCASE","uppercase","char at index","flow"};


        for (String name: strings){     
            System.out.println(name.toLowerCase());
            System.out.println(name.toUpperCase());
            System.out.println(name.charAt(3));
            System.out.println(name.length());
        }   
    }    
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Looking at that code and running it makes me realise that my question was nonsensical. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what is the logic you are trying to accomplish, the order you iterate the names in the println part is kinda random.
What you can do is define array of `Function`s and then for each name in index `i` apply the relevant function in the same index:

```java
Function<String,String>[] funcs = new Function[] {
  (Function<String,String>) (s) -> s.toUpperCase(),
  (Function<String,String>) (s) -> s.toLowerCase()
};
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(funcs[i].apply(names[i]));
}
```